# find() method - two implementations two results

Tags: javascript

I have a question about implementation of find() method. 
e.target.value is a value of checkbox, finding is started after pressing it.

In first implementation after calling finding() i always get "undefined" as a result. What can be the reason?

Thanks!

```
const table = ['e', 'f', 'e']

//1
function finding() {
    table.find(el=>{
      return el === e.target.value;
    })
  }

//2
  let finding = table.find(el=>{
    return el === e.target.value
  })
```

Comment: In the first version, `finding` does not return anything.

Comment: returning from `table.find()` wouldn't make an implicit return from the `finding()` function in the 1st case

Comment: BTW, when using an arrow function that just returns a simple expression, you can use the shortcut format: `table.find(el => el === e.target.value)`

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, put `return` in front of table.find(). This is the difference: your first example returns nothing, the second one does.